# How to capture user URL input and search on google in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, variables, browser

I am making this simple project in which the program captures the user input and searches it up on google.

For example , if %variable% is the URL the user types, then 
here is a "demo" of what I want:

```
start CHROME %variable%
```

---

Answer (Me)

I think I have an answer to my own question:

```
set /p urlinput=Search:

start CHROME %urlinput%

start CHROME google.com/search?q=%urlinput%*
```

I will be leaving this up in case people need to know the answer.

*You need to add Pluses between each word for the search to work

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Windows 10 for a search about javascript:

```
set /P URL_IN=""
< javascript
start chrome "https://www.google.com/search?q=%URL_IN%"
```

Where `< javascript` is the user input.

It is important to enclose the URL in quotes otherwise words get dropped after spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Answer (Me)

I think I have an answer to my own question:

```
set /p urlinput=Search:

start CHROME %urlinput%

start CHROME google.com/search?q=%urlinput%*
```

I will be leaving this up in case people need to know the answer.

*You need to add Pluses beteen each word for the search to work